# Object to an Array Django/Jquery

Tags: jquery, python, django

Passing a List: [0,8,9] to JQuery via context

```
  json_array = json.dumps(thearray)
  return render(request, "page.html",{

  'thearray': json_array,
   })

 var cities = {{ thearray|safe }};
    console.log(typeof cities); - >
```

returns object and not an array.
Thus when doing cities it returns the first value only. Done various attempts to solve this problem such as .toArray() but 'toArray is not a function'. I need to get all the values out of the array so need some way to convert it to an Array.

I tried checking the type of it in Python/Django view and it is class list. However it's being converted to an object.

if I do 
     console.log('object evt: %O', thearray);
console prints
    object evt: Array[3]
    0: 5 
    1: 8 
    2: 4 
    length: 3
   **proto**: Array[0]

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
var cities = JSON.parse({{ thearray }})
```